# How can I use backbone.js to regularly check a remote data source and update a table?

Tags: backbone.js

Specifically, I have a standard `<table>` and I want the rows to update as new data comes in or out. My data comes in as a JSON object and if a new item is there, I want to add a row to my table in the corresponding location (meaning order matters). If an item isn't there, I want to remove the `<tr>`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: easy solution - run a fetch every 1 min lets say on the collection and then run a smart update using collection.set(). Then bind the rows to the model id...so if a new model comes in its added, if one is updated the corresponding row changes

Comment: what if one `isn't there` I don't think running a .set will work. I would just re-render the whole table once you pull in data. Easiest way to get it done.

Comment: Have you gotten a chance to look at my answer at all? Do you have any questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/phw4t/

Here you go, hopefully the code is simple enough to follow... a Backbone.js clock.

Basically the idea is that you put a collection inside of a view. Then you make the collection fetch data periodically using a `setInterval` and call .fetch({ 'reset': true }) so that the `reset` event will be triggered once the collection has a new set of data. Have the view listen to the collection's `reset` event and then render the table.

It's a lot easier to just re-render the data instead of trying to figure out what data has changed, what data was removed, and what data was added. You'll end up with the same result if you do it the hard way, or by just re-rendering the whole table. As long as you optimize you're DOM insertions (only write to the DOM once... render offscreen) there won't be a performance hit.

```
var PollingCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "path/to/data/source",
    model: new Backbone.Model(),
    initialize: function (model, options) {
        this.options = options;
        setInterval(function () {
            this.fetch({
                "reset": true
            });
        }.bind(this), options.pollRate);
    },
    /**
     * Overriding fetch for the example. If the URL was valid, delete the fetch
     * function below.
     */
    fetch: function () {
        this.reset([
        new Backbone.Model({
            "name": "current",
            "time": Date().toString()
        }),
        new Backbone.Model({
            "name": "next fetch",
            "time": "in " + this.options.pollRate / 1000 + " second(s)"
        })]);
    }
});

var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.pollingCollection = new PollingCollection(null, options);
        this.listenTo(this.pollingCollection, 'reset', this.render);
        /**
         * appending to body from within a view is 'bad'. normally another
         * view would place this in the HTML. Just keepin' it simple for
         * example
         */
        $('body').append(this.$el);
    },
    render: function () {
        // Render html into table then append. 1 DOM insert.
        var table = $("<table></table>"),
            html = this.renderTable();
        table.append(html);
        this.$el.html(table);
    },
    renderTable: function () {
        var tableRows = "";
        this.pollingCollection.each(function (model) {
            tableRows += this.renderRow(model);
        }, this);
        return tableRows;
    },
    renderRow: function (model) {
        return "<tr><td>" + model.get('name') + ":</td><td>" + model.get('time') + "</td></tr>";
    }
});

var tableView = new TableView({ "pollRate": 1000 }); // fetch data every 1000 ms
```